# What to do when a suggested edit is approved with errors

Tags: discussion

Several times, when a suggested edit fixes several errors, but does not fix all the errors even when they're very similar (for example, suggested edit fixes some spelling errors, some capitalisation errors, but not all), I've been trying to improve them, but the suggested edit has been approved before I can finish the suggested edits.

Should I be going and fixing the post (double-editing? rollback, then fix everything?)?

When a post has lots of errors and most-but-not-all are fixed, I could take the the view that fixing the rest is a "minor edit", and not worth the effort.

What's the communal view in this situation?

Comment: Sigh.  Here we go again with the minor edits business.  Just fix it, Spock.

Comment: Just continue editing, but do not rollback, unless it is a horrible suggested edit.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why you are looking for some sort of protocol here - there is none.

Personally, if the suggested edit was approved but there are still issues with the post that I can fix, I go in and fix them, over the suggested edit.

I see no point in rolling back just to make the same edits again.

No where does it say that an edit (suggested or otherwise) should fix *all* issues in a post. It is fine to have a bunch of edits each fixing bits of a post. Yes, it would be best to have less edits and more fixes in each edit, but that's not how people do things.

Comment: I think he's essentially asking if he should fix it if there is only one minor error remaining in the post after the suggested edit.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Well, if it bothers him so much, then I guess so ;)

Comment: There's a limit here though. If they fix one thing while leaving lots of other obvious problems it should be rejected, or Improved and marked Not Useful.

Comment: @BradMace - Sure. But at least they did go in and make an effort. I would probably go with an "improve" on such an edit. But the OP is asking about more substantive edits that have already been approved.

Comment: @BradMace Right. So if I saw an edit fixing one or two things, I'd reject. If I saw an edit *miss* one or two things but be approved, I can fix it, based on the comments attached to this question, *even when I'd reject the same edit if it came through on its own*?

Comment: @simont you can use the Improve option in either case. There's a checkbox you can use at the bottom to indicate whether the suggestion was useful.

Comment: @simont - If you have the rep, why not? I often correct posts with a single typo. Doesn't go into the edit queue as I have enough rep to show that I know a good edit from a bad one.