# What to do if you are sub 2000 rep and your incomplete edit was approved?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I recently suggested an edit to an answer. My suggestion was approved. When I then go back to look at the improved answer, I noticed that there is a small grammatical error as a result of my edit.

What can I do to fix this? I see two potential issues with suggesting another edit:

1. Making multiple (trivial) edit suggestions to a post might come off as intentional rep-whoring.
2. The following edit is too short, so I can't even suggest it.

Kind of related:

- [What to do when a suggested edit is approved with errors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143511/what-to-do-when-a-suggested-edit-is-approved-with-errors)
- [Reject an already-approved suggested edit when rolling it back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a minor error that I can't fix myself due to rep, I'll leave a comment on the question/answer noting the error and someone will usually fix it pretty quickly. I do this whether I've edited it or not if the change is really small. I try to check back when I see the question edited and remove my comment after the edit is done, too... just to keep things neat.

If you edit and then see some other errors and you can get over the edit character threshold by making legitimate corrections, I wouldn't worry too much about people calling you out as a "rep-whore" unless you do it repeatedly over the course of a few posts or edit the same thing several times.

To help avoid this, I strongly recommend a final once-over to make sure everything looks good before submitting the edit... though, since I have edit privileges on some sites and not others, I fall into this trap on the sites I don't have the privilege on from time to time.